# Getting data from table in database

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe, psycopg2

I want to extract data from a `postgresql` database and use that data (in a dataframe format) in a script. Here's my initial try:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host_address, database=name_of_database, user=user_name, password=user_password)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s;" % name_of_table)

the_data = cur.fetchall()

colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

the_frame = DataFrame(the_data)
the_frame.columns = colnames

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

*Note: I am aware that I should not use "string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string", but this works great for me as it is.*

Would there be a more direct approach to this?

*Edit: Here's what I used from the selected answer:*

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sq

engine = sq.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host:port/database")

the_frame = pd.read_sql_table(name_of_table, engine)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pandas can load data from Postgres directly:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas.io.sql as pdsql

conn = psycopg2.connect(...)

the_frame = pdsql.read_frame("SELECT * FROM %s;" % name_of_table, conn)
```

If you have a recent pandas (>=0.14), you should use `read_sql_query/table` (`read_frame` is deprecated) with an sqlalchemy engine:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://...")

the_frame = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM %s;" % name_of_table, engine)
the_frame = pd.read_sql_table(name_of_table, engine)
```

Comment: you don't need that deeper import anymore. `pandas.read_sql_query` is available from a top-level import now.

Comment: there's also, `pandas.read_sql_table`, which I believe will serve the OP even better

Comment: @PaulH: Thanks for that.  I'll leave my answer as it is though, to avoid depending on very new Pandas (my personal one is too old for `read_sql_query`, and it isn't that old).

Comment: @JohnZwinck I added the suggestion of Paul H (but left the old, so you have both), is that OK? I can also put it as a separate answer if you want

Comment: @JohnZwinck If I use `create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@ip_address/table_name')`, the call to `pd.read_sql_table('table_name', engine)` returns a `NotImplementedError` "read_sql_table only support for SQLAlchemy connectable". I tested `engine.has_table('table_name')` and it returns true. Why does Pandas think I'm not using an sqlalchemy connectable?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate method:

```
    # run sql code
    result = conn.execute(sql)   

    # Insert to a dataframe
    df = DataFrame(data=list(result), columns=result.keys())
```

Comment: Note that this wastefully constructs a list that isn't needed.  If the table is large, that will hurt performance.

Comment: You can, however, do `df = DataFrame(iter(result), columns=result.keys())` which is not quite as wasteful.